# flutter: how to use ExpansionPanelRadio value?

Tags: flutter

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelRadio-class.html

The value that uniquely identifies a radio panel so that the currently selected radio panel can be identified.

How to use the value? find a radio panel by value?

Why the ExpansionPanelRadio does not have key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
ExpansionPanelList.radio(

      initialOpenPanelValue: 1,
      children: [
        ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: "unique_id",
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("header value"),
              );
            },
            body: ListTile(
              title: Text("Expanded value"),
            ),
          );
      ]
    );
```

Comment: How could the value be used? thanks.

Comment: if you want to allow only one ExpansionPanel in expanded state at the same time. It's used to identify which radio panel is currently selected.